# Set "this" variable easily?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, this

I have a pretty good understanding of Javascript, except that I can't figure out a nice way to set the "this" variable.  Consider:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    alert(this.foo_variable);
}

var someObj = document.body; //using body as example object
someObj.foo_variable = "hi"; //set foo_variable so it alerts

var old_fn = someObj.fn;   //store old value
someObj.fn = myFunction;   //bind to someObj so "this" keyword works
someObj.fn();              
someObj.fn = old_fn;       //restore old value
```

Is there a way to do this without the last 4 lines?  It's rather annoying...  I've tried   binding an anonymous function, which I thought was beautiful and clever, but to no avail:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    alert(this.foo_variable);
}

var someObj = document.body;        //using body as example object
someObj.foo_variable = "hi";        //set foo_variable so it alerts
someObj.(function(){ fn(); })();    //fail.
```

Obviously, passing the variable into myFunction is an option... but that's not the point of this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

There are two methods defined for all functions in JavaScript, [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The function syntax looks like:

```
call( /* object */, /* arguments... */ );
apply(/* object */, /* arguments[] */);
```

What these functions do is call the function they were invoked on, assigning the value of the *object* parameter to **this**.

```
var myFunction = function(){
    alert(this.foo_variable);
}
myFunction.call( document.body );
```

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery, you can use `$.proxy(function, element)` so that whenever that function is called, it will be in the context of element. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/

Comment: Another usefull method is [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Note, [jQuery `$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) is deprecated as of 3.3. They state you should use the native [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) as suggested by @Soroush

Answer (score 59):

I think you're looking for [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
myFunction.call(obj, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

This calls `myFunction` with `this` set to `obj`.

There is also the slightly different method [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which takes the function parameters as an array:

```
myFunction.apply(obj, [arg1, arg2, ...]);
```

Comment: See section 15.3.4.3, 15.3.4.4 and 10.1.8 in ECMAScript Language Specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 20):

If you want to 'store' the `this` value to a function so that you can call it seamlessly later (e.g. when you don't have access to that value anymore), you can `bind` it (not available in all browsers though):

```
var bound = func.bind(someThisValue);

// ... later on, where someThisValue is not available anymore

bound(); // will call with someThisValue as 'this'
```

Comment: FYI `bind` is apparently available in IE9+, FF4+, Safari 5.1.4+ and Chrome 7+ [(source)](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind). You can also call bind directly on an anonymous function: `var myFunction = function(){ /* this = something */ }.bind(something);`

Answer (score 2):

My search on how to bind `this` brought me here so I am posting my findings: In 'ECMAScript 2015' we can also set this lexically using arrow functions to.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Instead of:

```
function Person() {
  setInterval(function growUp() {
    // The callback refers to the `self` variable of which
    // the value is the expected object.
    this.age++;
  }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

We can now do:

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Setting the `this` keyword in javascript.

Javascript has 3 built in methods for setting the `this` keyword conveniently. They are all located on the `Function.prototype` object so every function can use them (since every function inherits from this prototype via prototypal inheritance). These functions are the following:

1. `Function.prototype.call()`: This function takes the object which you want to use as `this` as a first argument. Then the remainder of the arguments are the respective arguments of the function which is called.
2. `Function.prototype.apply()`: This function takes the object which you want to use as `this` as a first argument. Then the second argument is an array which contains the values of the arguments of the function which is called (first element of array is first argument of the function, second argument of the array is second argument of function etc.).
3. `Function.prototype.bind()`: This function returns a new function which has a different value of `this`. It takes the object which you want to set as the `this` value as a first argument and then returns a new function object.

### Difference between call/apply and bind:

- `call` and `apply` are similar in the fact that they **immediately call the function** (with a predefined value of `this`)
- `bind` is different from `call` and `apply` in the fact that this function **returns a new function** with a different binding of the `this` value.

### Examples:

```js
const thisObj = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2,
};

function myFunc(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(this.prop1, this.prop2);
  console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

// first arg this obj, other arguments are the  
// respective arguments of the function
myFunc.call(thisObj, 'Call_arg1', 'Call_arg2');

// first arg this obj, other argument is an array which  
// are the respective arguments of the function
myFunc.apply(thisObj, ['Apply_arg1', 'Apply_arg2']);


// the bind method returns a new function with a different
// this context which is stored in the newMyFunc variable
const newMyFunc = myFunc.bind(thisObj);

// now we can call the function like a normal function 
newMyFunc('first', 'second');
```