# Can I change the context of javascript "this"?

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

```
var UI$Contract$ddlForm_change = function() {

    //'this' is currently the drop down that fires the event
    // My question is can I change the context so "this" represents another object? 
    this = SomeObject;

    // then call methods on the new "this"
    this.someMethod(someParam);   
};
```

is this possible?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456967/javascript-how-to-set-this-variable-easily

Comment: yepp, more or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456967/javascript-how-to-set-this-variable-easily
The accepted answer was to use call()/apply(), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: This is just TOO confusing. All of the answers say no, you can't do it. Apparently, the answers to the duplicate question way yes, you can do it. Go figure.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

You can call a method with a specified value for *this* (using **`method.apply()`**/**`method.call()`**) but you cannot re-assign the keyword, **`this`**.

Comment: more informations at [joshuakehn.com](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html)

Comment: You can also pass `this` as an argument to the function in the call to `UI$Contract$ddlForm_change`, then you can use that argument as the context/access its properties

Answer (score 11):

You can't change what `this` refers to from *inside* the function.

However, you can *call* a function in a specific context - so that `this` refers to a specific object - by using `call` or `apply`.

Answer (score 7):

J-P is correct.  This is not possible.  Refer to the JavaScript language specification document ECMA-262.  You can download the standard from here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

The file is ECMA-262.pdf and on page 39, section 10.1.7.

> 10.1.7 This
>
> There is a this value associated with
>   every active execution context. The
>   this value depends on the caller and
>   the type of code being executed and is
>   determined when control enters the
>   execution context. The this value
>   associated with an execution context
>   is immutable.

Note "is immutable".  i.e.  cannot be changed.