# Is it possible to have a javascript constructor return different object types?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I would like to do something like this:

```
function AjaxRequest (parameters) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        this = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (typeof ActiveXOBject != 'undefined')
        this = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

AjaxRequest.prototype.someMethod = function () { ... }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. No, I don't think so.  `this` is not settable.  You cannot change it, though you can add properties to it.  You can [make calls that cause `this` to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456967/javascript-how-to-set-this-variable-easily/456996#456996), but you cannot set it directly.

You can do something like this:

```
function AjaxRequest (parameters) { 
    this.xhr = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }
    else if (typeof ActiveXOBject != 'undefined') {
        this.xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }  
}

AjaxRequest.prototype.someMethod = function (url) { 
    this.xhr.open('Get', url, true);
    this.req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
        ...
    };
    this.xhr.send(...);
};
```

Stepping back, I think your design isn't very clear. What is it that you're trying to do? Another way to ask that is *What is the usage model you're shooting for* ?  What verbs do you want to expose from `AjaxRequest` What methods?

If you look at jQuery, their "ajax request" is not an object, it's a method.  `$ajax()....`

What's *your* idea?

That will determine how you use the xhr property, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying this out to see if I could make the Ajaxrequest an object. I'm new to javascript and thought it would make sense to treat each request as an object. But clearly I should go with functions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, there is at least some limited facility to set the value of `this` in JavaScript, using `apply()` and `call()`.  See:  http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: @aroth, That is noted in the answer.

Comment: @Lou - I don't know if i'd agree with *clearly you should go with functions.*  I'm just asking the question, *what do you want your object to do*?

Comment: Well I'd like the object to run the ajax-request. I'd like to be able to initialize a request (var foo = new ajaxRequest(params), then do something like myObject.send(params), and then be able to do result = myObject.responseText.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to return a different type of object from a constructor, but not exactly like what you're trying to do. If you return an object, instead of `undefined` (which is the default return value), it will "replace" this as the result of the `new` expression. The object won't get its prototype from the constructor though (and `x instanceof AjaxRequest` won't work).

This will get you close if that's how you want to do it:

```
function AjaxRequest (parameters) {
    var result;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        result = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (typeof ActiveXOBject != 'undefined')
        result = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    // result is not an AjaxRequest object, so you'll have to add properties here
    result.someMethod = function () { ... };

    // Use result as the "new" object instead of this
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Which solution would you consider 'cleaner', yours or the method suggested by Cheeso, where the 'object-to-differ' is stored as a field of the AjaxRequest-object?

Comment: I could go either way really, although returning a different type from a "constructor" could be confusing, since you would expect to be able to add methods to `AjaxRequest.prototype` and use `instanceof`. The downside to Cheeso's solution is that you have to either write wrappers to forward all the function calls to the real XHR object or access it directly (`like myObject.xhr.send()`).

Comment: Another (possible) benefit to Cheeso's solution is that you could define your own simpler interface, like what jQuery, Prototype, Dojo, etc. do.

Comment: This is the real answer - the answer to the title question (not the answer to "what should cheeso do in his super-specific design case")