# Avoid EVAL and pass THIS to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call, eval

I've built a GUI which passes in a long JS Object as settings for an animation plugin. One of the settings allows for the user to call a function once an animation is complete. Unfortunately, it has to be passed to the JS Object as a string.

```
... [ 'functioncall()' ] ......
```

Inside my animation callback, I'm retrieving this string and trying to run it as a function.

First attempt works perfectly, but uses eval...

```
eval( OS.path_jscall[index].path_jscall[0][i] )
```

I've setup a more preferred approach like so:

```
var HookFunction=new Function( OS.path_jscall[index].path_jscall[0][i] );
HookFunction();
```

Both examples call the functioncall() function perfectly. I'm not sure how to pass (this) to the functioncall() though...

```
functioncall(obj){ console.log(obj); };
```

Everything keeps referring to the window. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: how to set "this" variable easily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456967/javascript-how-to-set-this-variable-easily)

Comment: "it has to be passed to the JS Object as a string" Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `HookFunction` is the name, you can do either a `call()` or `apply()`

```
HookFunction.call(this,arg1,arg2,...,argN);

//or

HookFunction.apply(this,[arg1,arg2,...,argN]);
```

the basic difference of the 2 is that `call()` receives your "this" and an enumerated list of arguments after it, while `apply()` receives your "this" and an array of arguments

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much, it needed an extra step of adding 'this' into the string call :) You're awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Use `.call` when calling your function.  `.call` assigns the first parameter to the `this` variable.

```
var myFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {
    alert(this);
}

myFunction.call(this, "arg1", "arg2");
```

Using your second example, you could do this:

```
HookFunction.call(this);
```