# Array subclass prototype sort

Tags: javascript

I'm curious how to go about implementing my own sort function on the Array object. Ignoring all the usual warnings/dangers about extending/overriding a built-in, consider this:

```
Array.prototype.sort = function() {
    this = mySortFunction(this);
    function mySortFunction(arr) { ... };
};
```

Inside the closure, `this` refers to the Array object `[number, number2, number3, etc.]`. How do I go about reassigning `this` to be the result of my internal sorting function? Is it possible?

Comment: I would like to be able to call `someArray.sort()` and not `someArray = someArray.sort()`

Comment: The native `sort` method mutates the array, you could make use of it. But I'd say don't do mutation, it's dangerous, counter-intuitive and can be the source of silly bugs, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems a little redundant:

```
Array.prototype.sort = function() {
    this = mySortFunction(this);
    function mySortFunction(arr) {
        arr = yetAnotherSortFunction(arr)
        function yetAnotherSortFunction(arr2) {...}
        // and so on...
    };
};
```

If you really want to do it this way, why not reference your array directly in the first place:

```
Array.prototype.sort = function() {
    // your implementation:
    // for (var i = this.length, ...
    //     if (this[0] == ...
    //         this[i] = ...
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Aha, I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. Early morning I guess? This makes things a bit trickier because I'm implementing a merge sort consisting of `divide(arr)` and `merge(left, right)`. After I have the result of calling `var sorted = divide(this)`, is there a clever way to update the `this` array to equal the new, sorted array?

Comment: To me, it feels wrong to do this, there must be a better way. However, you could have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/456996/2060966