# How do functions bound by event listeners inherit `this` object

Tags: javascript

Pure Javascript only please. - also I'm pretty noob, so sorry if my question is a little convoluted.

I'm operating on an htmlCollection `var puzzleAreaContents` - which contains 16 `<div>` tags

next we go inside a loop, cycling through the elements, adding a click event listener.

`puzzleAreaContents[movables[i]].addEventListener("click", shiftPuzzlePiece);`

when I click on the element, I have access to `this` inside the `shiftPuzzlePiece` function, "this" being the the `<div>` tag I just clicked on.

I have two questions

1. how / why does `shiftPuzzlePiece` function have access to `this`, the clicked dom element ?
2. how can I pass any arbitrary element to `shiftPuzzlePiece` without breaking it's current usability? -- How can I define `this` when I'm passing the function an object, so that it behaves the same or similarly to when it is called via the click event listener?

that is to say that it is not currently set up to receive arguments

ex: `shiftPuzzlePiece(some_arg)`

Comment: For question 2, are you asking how you can call the function and define what `this` is when called?

Comment: @JamesMontagne yes sir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456967/javascript-how-to-set-this-variable-easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The event handler creates a new **[Execution Context<sup>ECMA</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)** which binds this to the element clicked
2. You can use your own binding in order to replace `this` with **[call<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**.

For example,

```
shiftPuzzlePiece.call(puzzleAreaContents[movables[i]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you call a function as a statement/expression:

```
var ret = shiftPuzzlePiece(arg0);
```

There are also [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), with which you can provide the `this` context:

```
var ret = shiftPuzzlePiece.call(that, arg0);
var ret = shiftPuzzlePiece.apply(that, [ arg0 ]);
```

Now `that` becomes `this` inside the function.

---

Example

```
var piece = { };

puzzleAreaContents[movables[i]].addEventListener("click", function () {

    shiftPuzzlePiece.call(piece, this /* element */);

});

function shiftPuzzlePiece(element) {

   // this === piece
   // element === the clicked puzzleAreaContents

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind any value to be the `this` object by using `bind`.  For example:

```
shiftPuzzlePiece.bind({x:23});
```

Will ensure that the `this` object will have `this.x` equal to `23`.

You can also give pass in other parameters as well, but they would have to be in order.  Bind returns a function.

More info about bind [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

The `call` and `apply` functions work similarly, but they do not return a new function but instead call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way not mentioned here is using a `closure` which actually is faster than `apply()`, `call()` and `bind()`

```
(function f(){
  this.a = 0;
  var self = this;
  var e = document.getElementById('list').children, i;
  for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
      e[i].onclick = function(){
        _f(this, i);
      };
    })(i);
  }
})();
```

Or, it may be written like this as well

```
(function f(){
  this.a = 0;
  var self = this;
  var e = document.getElementById('list').children, i;
  for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].onclick = (function(i){
      return function() {
        _f(this, i);
      };
    })(i);
  }
})();
```

And finally, the `_f` function in this case

```
function _f(y, z){
  console.log(this.a + " / " + y.innerHTML + " / " + z);
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Output:

```
0 / 1 / 0
0 / 2 / 1
0 / 3 / 2
0 / 4 / 3
0 / 5 / 4
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/yukafoko/1/edit?html,js,output) | [Banchmark](http://jsperf.com/call-vs-apply-vs-bind-vs-closure)