# Access angular2 variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm using jQuery for some things in my angular2 projects. But I can't manage to use variables I've declared in angular2 to use in jQuery. I have something like this:

```
export class AddExerciseComponent implements OnInit {

  parameters:Array<string> = ["FU"];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {


    $('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, chip){
      this.parameters.push(chip.data);
      console.log(this.selectedValue);
    });
}
```

This would get me an error that parameters is not defined. I guess it's because I use `this`. What else can I do?

Comment: I never use Angular2, but is possible to add the variable to the scope like in angular 1?

Comment: I'm using Angular2 for a week now, so I'm not sure, but I don't think there is something like a scope in v2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: how to set "this" variable easily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456967/javascript-how-to-set-this-variable-easily)

Comment: What can you do? Read up on scope and `this` :). See the dupe, but basically, capture `this` in a variable, then use that variable in your event handler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use an **arrow function expression** (`() => {}`) to keep `this` in scope. Try:

```
export class AddExerciseComponent implements OnInit {

parameters:Array<string> = ["FU"];

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
// removed function keyword and added () => {} syntax
  $('.chips').on('chip.add', (e, chip) => {  
    this.parameters.push(chip.data);
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
  });
}
```

When you passed your callback as a regular old function, JavaScript doesn't consider your callback to be within the scope of the calling function, leaving `this` unusable for calling data from the scope you thought you were in. By using an Arrow function, the scope is saved and `this` is usable for accessing data as expected.

Comment: Yay, that did it! Thanks!

Comment: perfect,  adding "()=>{ }" is conceptual and it works perfectly in my case too.

Comment: When I add this I am unable to use Javascript "this" and its properties. Any solution to access those values

Comment: Arrow functions are an ES6 feature that skips giving the function its own `this`, instead referencing the lexical context it's contained in. If you're not familiar with how `this` works in JS (It's not actually referencing the class scope like in most OOP languages), then you should read the amazing "You Don't Know JS" chapter (https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md) on the topic to get a better handle on what's going on. After that, you'll need to avoid using arrows if you need to use `call(thisArg, args)` or similar binding methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use angular variables in jquery animate ON-Complete function call back,that's how you do it:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({top: 70+"%"},{

  queue: false,
  duration: 1000,
  complete: () => {  

  //this is you angular variable of the class
      this.angularVar = 0;
      $("#myDiv").hide();

  //this is you angular variable of the class    
      this.showAnimation = false;

  //this is you angular class function
      this.angularFunction();

      console.log("animation complete");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign angular's **this**(instance) to Jquery's **this**(instance) to use the angular variable inside JQuery

```
let jQueryInstance = this; // This line will assign all the angular instances to jQueryInstance variable.
$('.chips').on('chip.add', (e, chip) => { 

    /* this.parameters.push(chip.data); */

    // Instead of the above line we have to use like below
    jQueryInstance.parameters.push(chip.data); // instead of "this", "jQueryInstance" is used

    // console.log(this.selectedValue);
    console.log(jQueryInstance.selectedValue);
  });
```