# access angular 2 variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, froala

Following the example of Asad in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753505/access-angular2-variables-in-jquery/46032774#46032774), I do not know how to refer to the object this of the javascript itself and angular varibale.

```
// Original code, the angular variable don't work

$.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insert', {
                title: 'Insert Read More',
                focus: true,
                undo: true,
                refreshAfterCallback: true,
                callback: function () {
                  this.html.insert('<span class="readMore">'+this.angularVariable+' </span>');
                }
              });

// using fat arrows, the angular variable works but this.html.insert fails

$.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('insert', {
                        title: 'Insert Read More',
                        focus: true,
                        undo: true,
                        refreshAfterCallback: true,
                        callback: () => {
                          this.html.insert('<span class="readMore">'+this.angularVariable+' </span>');
                        }
                      });
```

Comment: This depends on where your above code is placed, but the question doesn't provide any information about that.

Comment: where have you initialised this.html ? show the code please...

Comment: The froalaEditor inits this.html, it's a jquery method, not angular https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/custom-buttons