# How to use Angular 4 variable inside Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

This question has already got some response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753505/access-angular2-variables-in-jquery). But this doesn't seem to be working for me.

I am trying to create a tree structure using jQuery. The problem is I can not use a declared angular 4 variable inside a jQuery function. Here's the code.

```js
employees = ["Mr. John", "Mr. Steve"];

ngOnInit() {
   (function($) => {
      function OrgChart($container, opts){
          console.log(this.employees);
      }
   });
}
```

I see an error in console stating, "Function declarations are not allowed inside blocks in strict mode when targeting ES3 or ES5"

Comment: It might be helpful if you can describe step-by-step, what you think this code is supposed to do.  Here's what it does now:

1) On initialization of the Angular component,

2) Declare an anonymous function that takes a single argument, $,

3) Within this anonymous function, a named function OrgChart is declared, which takes two arguments, $container and opts.  

4) Within the OrgChart function, the console method log is called with a single argument, which is the component's property employees.

At no point is either the anonymous function or the named function OrgChart called.

Answer (score 3):

### 1st (the `employees of undefined` problem)

To bind the "this" of the component, use the arrow notation for functions :

```
($) => { console.log(this.employees)}
```

instead of `function($) { ... }`

### 2nd (the "function declarations are not allowed inside blocks")

You could declare your other inner function in another place in your Angular component, and then refer to it :

```
ngOnInit() {
    // this declaration is nonsense to me, this will declare a function that is never called and exists only here, but anyway... 
    ($) => {
        // you can call OrgChart here : 
        this.OrgChart()
    } 
}

OrgChart($container, opts) { 
    console.log(this.employees); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this doesn't seem to solve the purpose. I have modified the question as I am still getting an error even when I follow this.

Comment: I just saw your edit, so it becomes another question now. 

I still don't  really understand what you are trying to do, but as a remark : With the arrow notation, you mustn't write the keyword "function".
Also, what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I must be rusty with jQuery, but the more I look at this code, the more I'm thinking that it is doing litteraly nothing.

Comment: This is a modified part of the code where the problem exists. There is a bunch of other jQuery stuff which exists inside the OrgChart function which builds a hierarchical tree structure for me using jQuery.  Just that I need to use an employees array declared outside this function to build the tree rather than using some dummy data declared inside the function.

Comment: Ok, not sure how to answer since I can't really test this myself, but I tried to show some additional clue for this second problem.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Will try to implement and get back :)

Answer (score 0):

You need store angular component reference in another variable before start jquery block.

```
export class PlanGruposComponent implements OnInit {
   group = 'Meu grupo';

   OnInit() {

       //reference of currect component object
       let temporaryThis = this; 

       $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log("Print : " + temporaryThis.group);
       });

   }
}
```